# why composer update causes laravel app to fail on redirects

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, composer-php

I have a laravel app (version 5.5) that I have been developing for months.
For the longest time I could add new libraries in my composer.json file and run "composer update" so it would build a new composer.lock file and everything worked just fine. But now when ever I run composer update and I restart my laravel app, any thing I do which would cause the site to attempt a "redirect" (such as login or logout) produces the following error:

Type error: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::__construct() must be an instance of Laravel\Lumen\Application, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in ... (depends on where I am doing a redirect)

so I am sure this must be caused by some package not properly updating. So if I simply delete the entire ..\vendor folder and then run composer install, it will fix the issue. Site will run fine for months then if I run composer update again the error comes back. So I know it is being caused by one of the packages being included. Does anyone know what to do to try to figure out what, or how or which package is causing this error?

In case you need it here is a copy of the composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^2.3",
    "askedio/laravel5-soft-cascade": "^5.5",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.25",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravolt/avatar": "^1.8",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg": "^1.1",
    "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.9.5",
    "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.5",
    "braintree/braintree_php" : "3.27.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
}
}
```

===============================================

Updated: To be clear I have searched my code for Laravel\Lumen and I find no references but when I search the \vendor folder I get several packages including Amazon AWS which does reference that (see below).... But how do I fix those packages?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel\Lumen` theres your answer. How come `Lumen` is being used?

Somewhere in your code you're importing the wrong class. The exception is stating that a `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` is being created, which is correct, but somewhere there is a type hint expecting `Laravel\Lumen\Application`. Do a search through your code for `Laravel\Lumen\Application` and you'll probably find the problem.

Comment: you are 100% correct. The error message its self is very clear. But I also stated all of "my" code works perfect when I remove the vendor folder and do a composer install. This error will reoccur if I try to do a composer update. I updated my original question showing where I find references to Laravel/Lumen. When I search my code I find no reference to Lumen. However there are several 3rd party packages that do reference that.  My problem is even listing a few packages that has that referenced is "how do I fix those packages?" when it only occurs after a "composer update"?

Comment: What version of 5.5.* are you running? I grepped my vendor directory of a large project on 5.5.28 and the word "Lumen" only came up once in a comment. Does "laravel/lumen-framework" show up anywhere?

Comment: as of today I am now running version 5.5.33. When I checked for laravel/lumen-framework it shows up in the Amazon AWS sdk composer.json file but appears to only be some type of string comment. Where as the package Askedio/laravel5-soft-cascade list contains the following in its composer.json file:
        "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.x",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.x"
         },

Comment: Can you remove `Askedio/laravel5-soft-cascade ` from your project temporarily and try updating without it? Or would it be too impactful?

Comment: Having both Laravel and Lumen listed as dependencies is just weird to me, I can't say I've ever seen that before.